# C++ text filtering template library/engine

Tags: c++, qt, templates, text, filter

I am looking for a c++ template library that can help me filter strings, quite like regular expressions. I am using the QT Creator IDE.

For example, i have a `"11,[7,8]495???????"` template and I only want strings that have 11 characters, starting with 7 or 8, followed by 495 and anything else for the last 7 to pass.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you not using regular expressions?

Comment: Qt has all for that, for example [qregularexpression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#details).

Comment: If you're searching for something like regular expressions, why not using regular expressions? If you're using Qt, you can use QRegExp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve performance use QRegExp to validate an string: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qregexp.html

Some Examples:

Matches integers 0 to 99

```
QRegExp rx("^\\d\\d?$");    // match integers 0 to 99
rx.indexIn("123");          // returns -1 (no match)
rx.indexIn("-6");           // returns -1 (no match)
rx.indexIn("6");            // returns 0 (matched at position 0)
```

Email validation

```
QRegExp mailREX("\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b");
mailREX.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
mailREX.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::RegExp);
```

How to use it?

```
qDebug() << "Email validation: " myREX.exactMatch("test@example.com");
```

Result:

```
"Email validation: true"
```